# Can someone tell me what this snippet of HLSL code means?

Tags: xna, hlsl

```
float4 color = tex2D(inputSampler, TexCoord);
     //compute distance from center
float distance = color.a&gt;0.3f?length(TexCoord - 0.5f):1.0f;
```

What is `color.a&gt` and why is there a `;` in the middle of that second line?

Comment: you shouldnt completely change the question after an accept. you should start a new question. You should revert your original version and start a new question.

Comment: I've fixed it. The new question was basically: "How do I use this HLSL code to shade things?" -- which I agree should be its own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Response to the original question**: "Can someone tell me what this snippet of HLSL code means?*

```
float4 color = tex2D(inputSampler, TexCoord);
  //compute distance from center 
float distance = color.a&gt;0.3f?length(TexCoord - 0.5f):1.0f;
```

*what is color.a&gt and why is there a ; in the middle of that second line?"*

---

Its a html escape sequence screwup. `&gt;` should be `>` ("greater than" symbol).

So it should be:

```
float4 color = tex2D(inputSampler, TexCoord);
     //compute distance from center
float distance = color.a > 0.3f?length(TexCoord - 0.5f):1.0f;
```

Likewise if you encounter `&lt;` it is probably `<` ("less than" symbol). Other common ones ones are:

- `&quot;` -> '`"`'
- `&amp;` -> '`&`'
- `&nbsp;` -> ' ' (space)

What the pixel shader is actually doing is if the alpha of the sampled texture at this point is greater than `0.3`, `distance` is the length from the sampled texcoord (U,V) location to (0.5, 0.5) i.e. the center of the texture sampled from. If the alpha is `0.3` or less, then `distance` is set to `1.0f`.

The distance value is obviously used later in the shader to apply some pixel effect.